# Haskell & gtk2hs, button activated signal not binding

Tags: haskell, gtk2hs

I'm having trouble with generating buttons from a list of labels and actions.
I'm pretty sure it's something to do with an IO not getting evaluated (the 'on button buttonActivated action'), but I'm not certain how to fix it.

I have a list of (Label, Command) tuples, which I use to generate a Button, and it's associated IO () action.

The function that calls: 'on button buttonActivated action' gets called, but the button doesn't register clicks still.

```
module GtkTest where

import qualified Data.Map as M
import Graphics.UI.Gtk
import Graphics.UI.Gtk.Buttons.Button
import Graphics.UI.Gtk.Windows.Window
import Graphics.UI.Gtk.Layout.VBox
import Control.DeepSeq

type Command = String
type ButtonLabel = String
type ButtonAction = IO ()
type ButtonDesc = (ButtonLabel, Command)
data ButtonInfo = ButtonInfo {
    buttonLabel :: ButtonLabel
  , buttonAction :: ButtonAction
  , buttonIo :: IO Button
  }

genAction :: Command -> ButtonAction
genAction command = putStrLn ("Running: " ++ command)

genButton :: ButtonDesc -> ButtonInfo
genButton info = let (label, command) = info
                 in ButtonInfo label (genAction command) (buttonNewWithLabel label)

getButtonDescs :: IO [ButtonDesc]
getButtonDescs = return [("Ok", "ok"),
                         ("Foo", "foo"),
                         ("Bar", "bar")]

applyAction (ButtonInfo _ action io) = do
--This gets called
  putStrLn "applying click handler"
  button <- io
--But apparently not this
  on button buttonActivated action

addIoToContainer container io = do
  widget <- io
  containerAdd container widget

main = do
  initGUI
  window <- windowNew
--These buttons do not work
  buttonDescs <- getButtonDescs
  buttons <- return $ map genButton buttonDescs
  vbox <- vBoxNew True 0
  _ <- sequence $ map ((addIoToContainer vbox) . buttonIo) buttons
  _ <- sequence $ map applyAction buttons
  _ <- containerAdd window vbox
-- This button works
  button <- buttonNewWithLabel "Manually made"
  on button buttonActivated $ genAction "Manual action"
  containerAdd vbox button
  onDestroy window mainQuit
  widgetShowAll window
  mainGUI
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT:

As per chi's answer, I updated the ButtonInfo data type to not do IO, and ended up with an IO [ButtonInfo], which allowed me to bind the action.

Revised source (working):

```
module GtkTest where

import qualified Data.Map as M
import Graphics.UI.Gtk
import Graphics.UI.Gtk.Buttons.Button
import Graphics.UI.Gtk.Windows.Window
import Graphics.UI.Gtk.Layout.VBox
import Control.DeepSeq

type Command = String
type ButtonLabel = String
type ButtonAction = IO ()
type ButtonDesc = (ButtonLabel, Command)
data ButtonInfo = ButtonInfo {
    buttonLabel :: ButtonLabel
  , buttonAction :: ButtonAction
  , buttonWidget :: Button
  }

genAction :: Command -> ButtonAction
genAction command = putStrLn ("Running: " ++ command)

genButton :: ButtonDesc -> IO ButtonInfo
genButton info = let (label, command) = info
                 in do
                   button <- (buttonNewWithLabel label)
                   return $ ButtonInfo label (genAction command) button

getButtonDescs :: IO [ButtonDesc]
getButtonDescs = return [("Ok", "ok"),
                         ("Foo", "foo"),
                         ("Bar", "bar")]

applyAction (ButtonInfo _ action widget) = do
  putStrLn "applying click handler"
  on widget buttonActivated action

addIoToContainer container io = do
  widget <- io
  containerAdd container widget

main = do
  initGUI
  window <- windowNew
  buttonDescs <- getButtonDescs
  buttons <- sequence $ map genButton buttonDescs
  vbox <- vBoxNew True 0
  _ <- sequence $ map ((containerAdd vbox) . buttonWidget) buttons
  _ <- sequence $ map applyAction buttons
  _ <- containerAdd window vbox
  button <- buttonNewWithLabel "Manually made"
  on button buttonActivated $ genAction "Manual action"
  containerAdd vbox button
  onDestroy window mainQuit
  widgetShowAll window
  mainGUI
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you can use `sequence_` rather than `_ <- sequence`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I can see, the `buttonIo` field of `ButtonInfo` stores an action which creates a fresh button every time it is run. Because of this, the code

```
applyAction (ButtonInfo _ action io) = do
  putStrLn "applying click handler"
  button <- io   -- (1)
  on button buttonActivated action

addIoToContainer container io = do
  widget <- io   -- (2)
  containerAdd container widget
```

looks wrong since `addIoToContainer` creates a new button (line `(2)`) and adds it to the container, while `applyAction` creates another button (line `(1)`) with a `buttonActivated` action attached. So you get an unresponsive button on screen, and a responsive button off screen.

My suggestion would be to use

```
data ButtonInfo = ButtonInfo {
    buttonLabel :: ButtonLabel
  , buttonAction :: ButtonAction
  , buttonIo :: Button   -- no IO here!
  }
```

this will immediately cause a lot of type errors due to `IO Button` and `Button` being different types. This is good, because fixing these type errors will force you to create the buttons just once, so making them responsive and on screen.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't thought of the IO as storing the function to be called over and over again.